# scikit_image library is not installing

Tags: python, scikit-image

I am trying to install `scikit-image` library in `python 3.4.4`on windows. I am using the following command:

```
pip install scikit-image
```

I am installing it in the following path

```
C:\Python34\Scripts
```

It's not working showing the following error:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Usman\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-utv6_a2u\scikit-image\
```

I tried also installing it through the .whl file,, but still it's not working.
Pip version is

```
pip 9.0.1
```

Please tell me what should I do?

Comment: Make sure you have `setuptools` installed, and make sure you have permission to write to that directory.  A lot of paths in C:\ need elevation to write to.  You can try: Windows-Key >> type `cmd` >> right-click on the `cmd` icon >> Run as Administrator >>  run `pip install` again

Comment: @James `You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help install")`
Following error pops up.

Comment: We do not currently have a python 3.4 wheel uploaded for Windows; my apologies for that.  You can install scikit-image either from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ or via Conda.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run one of the following and than try to install again the requested library.

`pip install --upgrade setuptools` or `easy_install -U setuptools`

As setuptools contains a lot of important files including egg files, it can cause problems when it's not updated\installed.